# extension of field of arbitrary degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is the following statement true?

Let $F$ be a field and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists an extension $E$ of $F$ with $[E:F]=n$.

---

I'm thinking of $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=2$ and since I can not think of another extension of the real numbers, this would be a counterexample. But I do not know a rigorous argument, why there can not be other extensions of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Better think of extensions of $\mathbb{C}$. That is algebraically closed, hence all algebraic extensions are ...

Comment: All extensions are? I do not know.. We extended fields by "adding" roots of minimal polynomials. Ok, in $\mathbb{C}$ this can not be done. But I do not see why I should know, that there is no other way to extend a field, like adding _hullahupp_ or anything..

Comment: Oh, you _can_ extend fields in another way. Those are then _transcendental_ extensions. But an extension of finite degree is _algebraic_, which means obtained by adjoining roots of polynomials.

Comment: Ah, then it is clear. Every finite extension is algebraic, since $\mathbb{C}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ and $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=2$ all finite extensions have either degree $1$ or $2$. q.e.d. Are there infinite extensions of $\mathbb{R}$? What are those other ways to extend a field?

Comment: Transcendental extensions. The archetypical transcendental extension is $K(X)$, the field of rational functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated in a comment, the result is false in general: Algebraically closed fields only have transcendental extensions, which have infinite order.

The question of whether numbers other than $2$ are possible is very interesting. Any extension of $\mathbb R$ is either transcendental, or of degree $2$ (and isomorphic to $\mathbb C$). In fact, if $[E:F]$ is finite and $E$ is algebraically closed, then $[E:F]=2$, and $F$ "looks a lot" like $\mathbb R$. Technically, $F$ is what we call a [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) so, in the sense of model theory, it has the same first-order properties as the reals. In particular, any finite extension of $F$ is isomorphic to $E$, and $E$ is just $F(i)$, where $i^2=-1$.

This result is the Artin-Schreier theorem. A very nice, accessible presentation, can be found in [this write-up](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) by Keith Conrad.